# How can I mock a select statement with count and sum in SQLAlchemy using mock-alchemy for unit testing?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking

I have a Sql Alchemy 2.0.6 DB Model like this:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    owner_name= Column(String(255), index=True, nullable=False)
    size = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

My productive code looks like this:

```
select_statement = select(func.count(Model.id).label("number_of_items"),
               func.sum(Model.size).label("size_of_all_items"))
query_response = CURRENT_SESSION.query(select_statement).filter(Model.owner_name==name).group_by(Model.owner_name).first()
```

Now I want to write a unittest for this code using mock_alchemy. I tested other code with it just querying entities and it works fine. However I can't get it to mock this select statement.

My current testcode is looking like this

```
    select_statement = select(func.count(Model.id).label("number_of_items"),
                              func.sum(Model.size).label("size_of_all_items"))

    session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(
        data=[
            (
                [mock.call.query(select_statement),
                    mock.call.filter(Model.owner_name== "some_name"), mock.call.group_by(Model.owner_name)],
                [RowHelper({"number_of_items": 2,
                            "size_of_all_items": 3})],
            )
        ]
    )
```

However the query in my productive code always returns an empty result when running with the mock session.
I already tried to use the toString method on the select query and pass this in the mock. But this just leads to the same result. I also tried the session.add method and just add Model objects as expected. This also leads to an empty query.

As a last option I could rewrite the code to query all Model objects and filter through them in the code. However, I don't want to make the productive code worse just to be able to test it.

This is the only DB call in the method I am testing. So just a way to mock all calls to the session would also be fine. I would however prefer to still use mock-alchemy instead of a other mock framework to avoid mixing different mocking frameworks in my tests.